# estoy usando phpstreadsheet , pero en hoja graficos no me dibuja nada, tampoco generar ningun error

Tags: php

Estoy usando la libreria php spreadsheet, estoy creando una hoja con el reporte y una con graficos , el tema es que en la hoja graficos no esta dibujando el grafico, tampoco genera ningun tipo de error

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $hoja = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    
    $data = [
         ['Nombre', 'Edad'],
         ['Juan', 25],
         ['Maria', 30],
         ['Pedro', 22],
         ['Victoria', 31],
    ];
    
    
    $hoja->fromArray($data, null, 'A1');
    
    
    $chartSheet = $spreadsheet->createSheet();
    $chartSheet->setTitle('Gráficos');
    
    
    $dataSeriesLabels = [
        new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Gráficos!$B$1', null, 1),
    ];
    
    $xAxisTickValues = [
        new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Gráficos!$A$2:$A$5', null, 4),
    ];
    
    $dataSeriesValues = [
        new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Gráficos!$B$2:$B$5', null, 4),
    ];
    
    
    $plotArea = new PlotArea(null, [$dataSeriesValues]);
    
    
     $chart = new Chart('Gráfico de Barras', null, null, $plotArea);
     $chart->setTopLeftPosition('A1');
     $chart->setBottomRightPosition('I10');
    
    
     $chartSheet->addChart($chart);
    
    
     $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
     $writer->save('archivo.xlsx');
```

Comment: no veo las etiquetas del eje X

Answer (score -1):

No sé si considerarlo un error tipográfico la omisión de código, pero evaluando tú código parece que le faltan los datos del eje X:

```
$chart->setXAxisTickValues($xAxisTickValues);
$chart->setSeriesLabels($dataSeriesLabels);
```

Échale un ojo a esta implementación:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57244317